# How to delete a folder with content to recycle bin in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, directory, recycle-bin

I am running Matlab R2020b on Windows 10.

Is there a way to move a folder with content to recycle bin programmatically in Matlab?

For example, the following works for single files

```Matlab
previousState=recycle('on');
delete(filename); % if replaced with rmdir(DIR,'s');, folder is deleted permanently
recycle(previousState);
```

but the same toggle doesn't work for folders. Is there a way?

---

The only possible workaround I can think of is to use wildcard: `delete(fullfile(DIR,'*')` and then `rmdir(DIR)` on the empty folder. But that doesn't work for my application. I wish to preserve temporary copies of folders in recycle bin in case my script that manipulate them throws warning in some unexpected way, in which case I can have a second chance to see the original files. There are hundreds of folders, each contain hundreds to thousands of files in this particular use case. The wildcard approach does put individual files into recycle bin but it loses the original folder structure, making it impractical to selectively recover folders. Hence the question.

Comment: You can use wildcards in `delete`. `delete(fullfile(DIR,'*'))` deletes all files in the DIR directory.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I was just editing that in. It doesn't work in my application unfortunately. Reasons in the edit.

Comment: How about just renaming the directory then? Maybe move it into `/tmp` or something like that.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I'll probably do just that. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I just realized too that we can call powershell script indirectly in Matlab. It's slow though.

Comment: Yes, of course! I never think of that because I worry about platform independence, but if you’re running on Windows only, there’s no reason not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OS is specifically Windows 10, one can use powershell as shown [here](https://superuser.com/a/24689/295139).

For example, with the following `recycleFile.ps1` file in `C:\`

```ps
Param(
  [string]$filePath # can be folder
)

$sh = new-object -comobject "Shell.Application"
$ns = $sh.Namespace(0).ParseName($filePath)
$ns.InvokeVerb("delete")
```

the following passage in Matlab will move the folder `fullfilepath` to recycle bin,

```matlab
[status,cmdout]=system(['powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "',...
                            fullfile('C:','recycleFile.ps1'),'" "',...
                            fullfilepath),'"']);
```

There are several downsides, however.

The operation is equivalent to `context menu` -> `delete`. It will bring up the recycle progress UI which seizes foreground. It is also somewhat slow. It may even require user confirmation if the folder in question is not eligible for recycling but only for direct deletion.

Comment: Doesn’t `del …` move things to the recycle bin in Windows? I haven’t used Windows a lot in the last 10 years or so, so I’m not sure…

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I just tried it. It deletes permanently. (That said I am overloading my system's I/O atm.) In any case, `del` won't delete single folders. It only delete all files in a folder (leaving the parent folder in place....) and adding to that, probably can't recycle files either.